# Making a View occupy a fixed width in Android layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have this as part of my layout:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.15">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/question_text"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/score_label" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/score_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The first `TextView` is empty at the beginning of the application. Its content is changed dynamically. This makes it occupy zero space so that the second `TextView` is aligned to the left, even though its `layout_gravity` is set to `right`.

**How can I make it occupy a fixed width, without taking the contents into account?**
I thought about using `layout_weight`, but I know the recommendation is against using nested weights (the parent `ViewGroup` has a `layout_weight` attribute). Maybe I should use a `RelativeLayout`?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You could add an image of the layout (a screenshot or a sketch is sufficient) to your post. This would help others to understand the layout much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all of your `TextViews` width set to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` which means that if there's nothing in there it will have no width.  You need to set that to either `"match_parent"` which will make it the same width as it's parent container or set it to a fixed value, something like `android:layout_width="100dp"`.

Comment: Actually the first TextView's width is 0dip, which is equivalent to fill/match_parent.

Comment: It's only equivalent to fill_parent / match_parent if you also set the layout_weight to 1.

Answer (score 3):

I solved a similar problem using the attribute `android:ems="<some number>"` on the `TextView`. An "ems" is the width of the character "M". This attribute makes the TextView exactly the given no. of ems wide. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Comment: Ok, I'll check it, but if anyone else has another idea, they are welcome to answer.